# How to dump data stored in objective-c object (NSArray or NSDictionary)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gdb, dump

Forgive me for a potentially silly question here, but in other programming languages (scripting ones like PHP or Perl) it is often easy to dump everything contained within a variable.

For instance, in PHP there are the `var_dump()` or `print_r()` functions. Perl has the `Data::Dumper` CPAN class, etc etc.

Is there something like this for Objective-C? It would be very convenient in a few cases to be able to dump everything like that, instead of using gdb to inspect each variable.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299841/objective-c-introspection-reflection

Comment: Handy: `[myview recursiveDescription]`

Answer (score 76, accepted):

In Cocoa, there is no "dump" like PHP's print_r or python's **repr** since there is no textual format that "represents" an object as in those languages. If you use

```
NSLog(@"%@", myObj);
```

or

```
NSString *stringRep = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",myObj];
```

or

```
NSString *stringRep = [myObj description];
```

you will get (logged to console in the first case), the result of `[myObj description]`, a method defined in `NSObject` for the purpose of printing a *description* (**not** a dump) of an object.

If you invoke `po myObj` in gdb, you get `[myObj debugDescription]` (often the same as `description`, but not always).

Classes like `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` and `NSData` override `description` to print a pretty useful recursive description of their contents, but the default `[NSObject description]` prints only the pointer value corresponding to the instance.

If you control the code for the types in question, you can override their `description` or `debugDescription` methods to return anything you want. If not, you could override the `description` or `debugDescription` method using a category, or use a category to define a `myDebugDescription` or some such that you could then invoke from gdb using `po [myObj myDebugDescription]`.

Comment: the `description` method is just what i need! Thanks for the information! :)

Comment: Always get message like this: <ObjectName: 0x608000482530>

Answer (score 17):

you can also use the gdb print object command to quickly view an object in the debugger:

```
po dictionary
```

This will be basically the same as calling NSLog(...) from within your code.

Also useful when printing out NSData that contains ASCII data is:

```
p (char *) [data bytes]
```

Comment: This only prints the first few hundred bytes.  How can I make it print all of them?

Answer (score 10):

Use NSLog() to dump contents of objects. For example:

```
NSData* myData = //... assume this exists
NSLog(@"Contents of myData: %@", myData);
```

NSLog has a printf-style format string (expects an NSString object) followed by a variable list of parameters, just like printf. The replacement character %@ represents an object the description method on an object. This is useful for dumping most Objective-C objects in Cocoa.

If you want to dump the contents of an object using gdb (I see you tagged this with gdb), use the special "po" directive instead of print. For example:

```
gdb) po myData
```

will cause gdb to dump the myData object. po is a shortcut for print-object.

Comment: The string formatted representation (used by NSLog and [NSString stringWithFormat:] et al.) may not be a full "dump" of the object. It is the result of the object's description method. Since objects can override this description, you may varying results from its use.

Comment: I know, which is why I said "This is useful for dumping /most/ Objective-C objects in Cocoa" but it is basically what the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 4):

Be careful with NSLog logging -> you most likely don't want it in production code.

You may want to use an alternate logging function that calls NSLog when your product is running in debug mode.

Comment: This is a good point. I lot of new Objective C programmers don't realise this. If you think of NSLog as being ObjC's printf or std::cout you shouldn't go far wrong (and writing a DLog wrapper macros is trivial).

Comment: You can use NSLog as much as you want. All you have to do is to add these lines on your .pch file, to magically strip all NSLog lines from release: `#ifndef DEBUG`  `#define NSLog(...)`  `#endif`   ... [see here](http://www.marekbell.com/update-stripping-nslog-output-for-xcode-release-builds/)

Answer (score 3):

I usualy go with this to "debug" NSArray contents:

```
NSEnumerator *arrenum = [myarray objectEnumerator];
id cobj;     
while ( cobj = [arrenum nextObject] ) {
   NSLog(@"%@", cobj);
}
```

The code will enumerate all objects in the NSArray `myarray`, and then iterate through and print every object.

Hope this can be useful for someone!