# Print_r equivalent for XCode? I just want to see my array's content

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am a web developer trying to make it in an Xcode world, and I need to see the contents of an array I have in my console, what are my options?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299841/objective-c-introspection-reflection

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no need to iterate through an array just to print it.

All the collection types have a -description method that returns a NSString of their contents. Just use the object format specifier **%@**

```
NSLog(@"%@", array);
```

Answer (score 1):

As an additional note you can dynamically print `NSArray`s and other objects in the debugger using `po object`. This uses the same `description` method that NSLog does. So it's not always necessary to litter your code with `NSLog`s, especially if you're already in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"a", @"b", @"Hello World", @"d", nil]; 
for (id obj in array) {

NSLog(@"%@", obj);

}
```

... which would log each item in the array to the console in their own separate `NSLog` messages.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want to see your `NSDictionary`'s content (which is comparable to a PHP associated `array()`), you could use:

```
for (id key in [dictionary allKeys]) {
    NSLog(@"Key: %@, Value: %@", key, [dictionary objectForKey:key]);
}
```