# iPhone : is there a way to loop through the attributes of an NSObject?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsobject

I have an NSObject defined as followed:

```
@interface MFMoodMix : NSObject {
    NSNumber *m1;
    NSNumber *m2;
    NSNumber *m3;
    NSNumber *m4;
    NSNumber *m5;
    NSNumber *m6;
    NSNumber *m7;
}
```

Is there any way I can loop through all these values quickly to find the largest one? e.g. like a UIView as for (UIView *x in view.subviews), is there a similar method to do this quickly?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

No. This is a terrible design. Use an array of NSNumbers instead.

```
@interface MFMoodMix : NSObject {
    NSArray *ms;
}
```

And then in your `init` method (or somewhere else) add the numbers to the array:

```
-(id) init
{
    /* ... */
    ms = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
             [NSNumber ...],
             [NSNumber ...], nil];
    /* ... */
}
```

To iterate, just an example considering the NSNumber(s) are int(s):

```
int high = 0; /* or a negative number... */
/* This is not Python */
for (NSNumber *n in ms)
    if ([n intValue] > high)
        high = [n intValue];
```

Comment: +1 for `/* This is not Python */`. I'd give another +1 for 'This is a terrible design', because it is.

Comment: -1 for 'This is a terrible design', because you don't have to be a douche.  Something like "No, but if you could replace the collection of NSNumbers with a single NSArray of NSNumbers, you could loop through that by ...' would have got the point across without being offensive.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a *collection* of similar values that you need to access in the same manner, I would recommend simply placing them into a... `collection`.  If you place these values into a `NSArray`, you can easily iterate through them and sort them any which way you'd like.  If you want to maintain the m* prefix, you could substitute a `NSDictionary` and use the *m* values as your keys.

Answer (score 1):

if you somehow can't convert your numbers to an array, you could always do it the hard way and use the objc runtime :-)

there is a great thread about it here on so: [Objective C Introspection/Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299841/objective-c-introspection-reflection)

Comment: Ah nice nice. +1 Always interesting to dive into these things.