# How to get the types of members in an object in order?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, reflection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Objective C Introspection/Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299841/objective-c-introspection-reflection)

I am looking for the way to get the object's members type name in sequence declared in the object header.

such as, if I get an object like this

```
@interface Person : NSObject {
  int age;
  NSString *name;
  PersonDetail *detail;
}
```

When I get the data like `{28,@"Jack",{@"basketball",@"Male",@"Master Degree"}}` in array.
I would need the type of members to fill the data in.

It's like in java where there is a function like getField() to get the members in order.

So is there any methods I can use?

Thank.

Comment: what do you mean by type of members?

Comment: They are like "int","NSString" and "PersonDetail" such things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Objective-C Runtime Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html). It includes functions for doing things like getting a class's ivar list (`class_copyIvarList()`), or get an objects actual ivars (`object_getIndexedIvars()`) and things like that. It should be able to do something like what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the type for above object  as follow:

```
   if( [person isKindOfClass:[Person class]])
    {
       //add your logic here
    }
```