# View object/property state in Xcode while debugging

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging

So I'm new to Xcode, working on an iOS project and I'm having a heck of a time with the most fundamental debugging. Specifically I need to be able to view the state of objects as I step through the code (that's not crazy is it?), but I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this in Xcode.

Whenever I try, it seems the furthest I get is a memory address that can't be expanded to show its objective contents. Nor can I figure out any way to even manually dereference the pointer in the debug console to view the state of that object.

Here I am trying to view the contents of the `store.storeHours` array, with no luck whatsoever. In fact the view on the left tells me there are 0 objects in the array, and won't show anything when I try to expand it, but when I `po store.storeHours` the console shows 7 objects, albeit uselessly portrayed as memory addresses.

[image]

Please tell me I'm not crazy and I'm just missing something!

**Update:** So things get even weirder! When I switch the variable display to "Local" instead of "Auto" suddenly, `self.store.storeHours` becomes fully navigable! I'm wondering if perhaps there was a glitch accessing the correct "storeHours" instance or something because it's clearly identifying 7 objects in the array when I view it now! Not to mention the objects are expandable as I was originally hoping.

[image]

Comment: `Hours` is your custom class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The instances are actually providing that information themselves. You need to implement the [`description`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000052-SW7) method, which is inherited from `NSObject`, for your custom classes in order for them to be able to print themselves as something other than a memory address (which is what `NSObject`'s implementation does).

I've no idea what properties your `Hours` class has, but this is as simple as something like:

```
- (NSString *)description
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Open: %i Close: %i", self.openTime, self.closeTime];
}
```

The method just needs to return an `NSString` containing whatever information you think is important to see when inspecting the object.

This is also how classes represent themselves when you use the `%@` format specifier in `NSLog()`.

Comment: Ok that is definitely a start. I can at least see what the Hours objects are now. It's unfortunate the default NSObject implementation can't just recursively show properties and values in a generic way. I guess Obj-C is too low level for that kind of stuff.

Comment: There are introspection facilities in the runtime library, so it's actually feasible for an object to just spit out all its properties, no matter what they are: http://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+-site:meta.stackoverflow.com+objective-c+print+all+properties+of+an+object

Comment: @chaiguy have a look at that super useful answer from kendall-helmstetter-gelner on proper introspection (which is what you are asking for); http://stackoverflow.com/a/2304797/91282

Comment: @JoshCaswell, Till Awesome that's good to know. Perhaps I can make use of the runtime introspection in some kind of reusable manner in my project.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, store.storeHours is an empty NSArray.  So, naturally, you can't look inside it.

For more clarity in the debugger, try adding a method (inherited from NSObject)

```
 - (NSString*) description
```

to your objects like `Hours` that tells you more about their contents.  See also `debugDescription`.

Comment: See that's what I would have thought too, but it's *not* empty, and when debugging, the for..in loop iterates over 7 objects, but I can't see that there are 7 objects unless I explicitly `po` storeHours in the console. Very confusing.

Comment: Are you on the latest version of Xcode, @chaiguy? LLDB was a bit buggy at the beginning with respect to viewing ivars.

Comment: It's the latest I think (4.5.2 (4G2008a)). The console says (gdb) though so presumably that means I'm not using LLDB?

Answer (score 0):

implement

```
-(NSString*)description{
    //Return a string in whatever way you like to describe this instance. That is what xcode debugger reads. 
    //This is implemented in the parent to return the address, that's why you see that way.
}
```

Comment: Can you expand on this answer a little?