# Similar method in ObjectiveC for 'java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField()'

Tags: java, objective-c, function, variables, methods

I am reading a text file. I want to check whether there is a variable declared in the class with name same as the text that I read from the file.

Method for this in java is 'java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField()'. See http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/class_getdeclaredfield.htm for details.

I was unable to find similar method in ObjectiveC. Is there any? If no, how I can implement the same. Please give me few tips for that if you get any idea.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299841/objective-c-introspection-reflection. Look at the first answer

Comment: @afsal: are you sure you need for ivar and there will be no property for those like @property/@synthesize?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Yes. I am sure.
For example         
long Id;
NSString* FirstName;

Comment: @AfsalMeerakutty: see my answers having for both. ivars and property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check like this: /*for properties*/

```
YourClass *arrObj=[YourClass new];//your target class where you wnat to check
NSString *propertyName=@"samllArray";//this is what you will check in class YourClass
if([arrObj respondsToSelector:NSSelectorFromString(propertyName)]){
    NSLog(@"yes, exists");
}
else{
    NSLog(@"no, it does not exists");
}
```

EDIT:/*for ivars*/

```
- (NSMutableArray *)getAllPropertyOfClass:(Class)aClass {
    NSMutableArray *mArray=[NSMutableArray new];
    unsigned int outCount;
    Ivar *ivars = class_copyIvarList([aClass class], &outCount); //class_copyPropertyList([aClass class], &outCount);

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < outCount; i++) {
        Ivar ivar = ivars[i];
        const char *propName = ivar_getName(ivar);
        if(propName) {
            NSString *propertyName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:propName];
            mArray[mArray.count]=propertyName;
        }
    }
    free(ivars);
    return mArray;
}
```

Comment: Close, but again, this is a poor replacement for actual introspection/reflection, and it doesn't account for iVars.  Prefer the runtime methods outlined in the dupe over this.

Comment: I thought obj-runtime will be costlier

Comment: Your method checks if the class implements the `samllArray` method, not it if has an instance variable called `samllArray`.

Comment: What does the speed of the runtime have to do with finding a comprehensive answer to this question?

Comment: Once I answered "Obj-C runtime" for similar question, then I was severely downvoted. I had a long discussion with DaveDLong. He used some great phrases. Now i am clueless, which way should I go. :(

Comment: I'd love a link to that question to get the context of the discussion you had.

Comment: I deleted my answer, after getting downvotes.

Comment: But what about the question?  Does it still exist?

Answer (score -1):

There are `respondsToSelector` and `conformsToProtocol` methods maybe they could help

Comment: Those have nothing to do with dynamic introspection/reflection.  A field in Java is analogous to an iVar, not a protocol.