# Set one objects properties to match another

Tags: ios, objective-c, object, properties

Lets say I have one object, maybe a `UIImageView`...

it is `.hidden = NO;`

the alpha is `.alpha = 0.425;`

the background color is `[UIColor blackColor];`

Is there anyway that if I have another `UIImageView` I can set all of the properties to match this `UIImageView's` properties.

```
imageView2.properties = imageView1.properties;
```

Maybe a `for-loop`? something like:

```
//for (properties *property in object1) {
```

Or do I have to just go through every possibility.

```
imageView2.alpha = imageView1.alpha;
imageView2.hidden = imageView1.hidden;
imageView2.backgroundColor = imageView1.backgroundColor;
imageView2.center = imageView1.center
//etc.
```

Comment: Do you have a fixed set of properties (e.g. hidden, background, alpha) or do you want it to find *all* properties at runtime?

Comment: You can take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299841/objective-c-introspection-reflection.

Comment: You can fairly easily use key-value coding to copy properties in a loop, but you need a list of the names of the properties to copy.

Comment: @MartinR I'd like code for _all_ properties but for now just a fixed list will do!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're working with a specific set of properties, you can build an array of their names and then use key-value coding to set them:

```
for(NSString * key in @[@"hidden", @"frame", @"backgroundColor"]) {
    [toObject setValue:[fromObject valueForKey:key] forKey:key];
}
```

If you want this to copy *all* properties of *any* object, you can get the list of declared properties for a class using the `class_copyPropertyList()` function in `objc/runtime.h`. This has a lot of caveats, though:

1. This call will return private properties that you shouldn't touch. As an example, gesture recognizers were only officially available in iOS 3.2, but they were a private class at least as far back as 3.1, and possibly in 3.0 as well.
2. It will return readonly properties, even though setting them may be dangerous (KVC can set instance variables, but doesn't necessarily know how to do so *correctly*) or even impossible.
3. It *won't* include anything that isn't in a property. For example, targets and actions for UIControls aren't exposed by a (public) property.
4. It won't necessarily know how to handle certain properties that can't be shared between two objects, like layout constraints.
5. A lot of very common data types—NSString, NSArray, and NSDictionary, for example—don't really store their data in properties, so this will completely miss the point on those sorts of classes.

In other words, it's very likely to break in horrible ways. Don't do it unless you *really* know what you're doing.

Comment: Your "caveat list" is better!

Answer (score 3):

For a *fixed list* of properties you can use Key-Value Coding:

```
NSArray *propList = @[@"alpha", @"hidden"];
NSDictionary *dict = [imageView1 dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:propList];
[imageView2 setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:dict];
```

You *could* copy all properties by using the Objective-C runtime function `class_copyPropertyList()` to determine the properties dynamically at runtime.
But I see two problems with that:

- Copying "internal" properties might cause unwanted side-effects.
- You would also have to copy the properties defined in the superclass. For example,
  `alpha` is not a property of `UIImageView` but of `UIView`.