# prevent reflection (objc/runtime) on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, reflection, static-libraries

I am working on a static library that handles sensitive data. It is imperative that the developer using the library can not use reflection on the library.

On Android, we solve the problem by developing an `aar` file with `service`s and run the `service` into separate process;(When the service is running into another process then the developer can not use reflection) but I am wondering if something similar exists in iOS ?

Can we execute a static library into a separate process? if not, how we can avoid reflection on our static libraries?

For example:

```
        MyTestObject *obj = [[[myTestView alloc] init ];

        //===========================================   

        Class clazz = [obj class];
        u_int count;
        Ivar* ivars = class_copyIvarList(clazz, &count);
        NSMutableArray* ivarArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:count];
        for (int i = 0; i < count ; i++)
        {
            const char* ivarName = ivar_getName(ivars[i]);
            [ivarArray addObject:[NSString  stringWithCString:ivarName encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        }
        free(ivars);

        objc_property_t* properties = class_copyPropertyList(clazz, &count);
        NSMutableArray* propertyArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:count];
        for (int i = 0; i < count ; i++)
        {
            const char* propertyName = property_getName(properties[i]);
            [propertyArray addObject:[NSString  stringWithCString:propertyName encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        }
        free(properties);

        Method* methods = class_copyMethodList(clazz, &count);
        NSMutableArray* methodArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:count];
        for (int i = 0; i < count ; i++)
        {
            SEL selector = method_getName(methods[i]);
            const char* methodName = sel_getName(selector);
            [methodArray addObject:[NSString  stringWithCString:methodName encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        }
        free(methods);

        NSDictionary* classDump = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   ivarArray, @"ivars",
                                   propertyArray, @"properties",
                                   methodArray, @"methods",
                                   nil];

        NSLog(@"%@", classDump);

        //======================================================

        int v2 = [[obj valueForKey:@"testValue"] intValue];

        SEL s = NSSelectorFromString(@"wannatTestIt");
        [obj performSelector:s];
```

`MyTestObject` is a class from my library. In the first line, I initialize an object from this class.

In the next line, I read the variables, methods and property list of the class and log it. Here is the result:

```
    {
    ivars =     (
        testValue
    );
    methods =     (
        printTestValue,
        wannatTestIt,
        "initWithFrame:"
    );
    properties =     (
    );
}
```

`wannaTestIt` is a private method and `testValue` is a private variable. So I expect that the developer that uses the library can not access them. However, because the user of the library could get the name, the user can ultimately call the method to read the value of the iVar.

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to completely "prevent" reflection then, well, you have to use a different language. Reflection is a key thing in Objective C and it's not possible to "block" or "disable" it.

However, you can make this run-time information much less useful for the researcher by obfuscating it. For example, take a look at this tool: https://github.com/Polidea/ios-class-guard. This is just an example. I'm not related to this particular project and you can freely chose a different obfuscator or write your own.

If what you need is to limit reflection to public API only and even disclosing *a number* of private methods and ivars (without their actual names) is not okay for you then you have no other choice than writing you sensitive code in a different language. You can use [Pimpl](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl) design pattern to achieve what you want. This way, your classes would only have public methods and a single private ivar `_impl` (or something like that). Where `_impl` is an instance of the implementation class that is written in C++ (or Objective C++ if you need access to ObjC APIs) and all public methods act like a proxy. Something like this:

```
- (NSInteger)computeSuperSensitiveStuffWithFoo:(Foo *)foo Bar:(Bar *)bar {
    return _impl->computeStuff(foo, bar);
}
```

This way all your private data and methods would be encapsulated in the `MyClassImpl` class. If you keep declaration and implementation of such class in private (i.e. do not distribute `MyClassImpl.h` file with your library) and use language like C++ for implementing it, then you will achieve what you want.

Also note that if you chose Objective C++ then `MyClassImpl` should be a C++ class (declared with `class` keyword) and not Objective C class (declared with `@interface`/`@end` block and implemented inside `@implementation`/`@end` block). Otherwise all you private data will be available for reflection anyway, but would require a couple of additional steps from the researcher.

Comment: my library have uiviewcontrollers too. Does we can develop codes with c++ that support uiviewcontrollers too?

Comment: @HuseinBehboodiRad, sure. No changes required for UIViewControllers. Just create an ordinary `UIViewController` subclass (say, `MyViewController`), create implementation class written in Objective C++ (say, `MyVCImpl`). And do exactly the same things that I described in my answer. In `MyViewController` add `_impl` ivar pointing to the instance of `MyVCImpl`. Proxy all public methods to `_impl` and keep all private methods/fields inside `MyVCImpl`. You can pass `self` to the constructor of `MyVCImpl` to have access to the actual view controller from the inside of implementation class.