# How can I inspect an objective c object?

Tags: objective-c, syntax

In ruby, I can .inspect from an object to know the details. How can I do the similar thing in objective c? Thank you.

Comment: Which is the real question? this one or that one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597186/how-can-i-inspect-an-objective-c-object, either way spamming with duplicates is frowned upon...

Comment: @tommieb75: given the questions' identical posting times and contents, I'd say it was a simple double-posting error.

Comment: Sorry, I think my network is unstable, so it posts two questions.

Comment: The other question has been closed, merged, and deleted, so I'm going to momentarily close this just to clear the close votes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want something to print you can use `description` as said before.

I'm not a Ruby guy myself, but if I understand this correctly `.inspect` in Ruby prints all the instance variables of an object. This is not something built into Cocoa. If you need this you can use the runtime system to query this information.

Here is a quick category I put together which does that:

```
#import <objc/objc-class.h>

@interface NSObject (InspectAsInRuby)

- (NSString *) inspect;

@end

@implementation  NSObject (InspectAsInRuby)

- (NSString *) inspect;
{
    NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat: @"<%@:%p", NSStringFromClass( [self class] ), self ];

    unsigned ivarCount = 0;
    Ivar *ivarList = class_copyIvarList( [self class], &ivarCount );

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < ivarCount; i++) {
        NSString *varName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: ivar_getName( ivarList[i] )];
        [result appendFormat: @" %@=%@", varName, [self valueForKey: varName]];
    }

    [result appendString: @">"];

    free( ivarList );

    return result;
}

@end
```

Comment: This method will not list any runtime or private iVars.

Answer (score 5):

`-[NSObject description]` provides a basic description of an object (similar to `toString` in Java--I don't really know about `.inspect` in Ruby).  `description` is automatically called in when you print an object in `NSLog` (e.g. `NSLog(@"@%", myObject)`).

For other introspection methods, I'd suggest looking at the [NSObject](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000050-62012) reference.  There are also a lot of things you can do directly with [the Objective-C runtime](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418-CH1g-TPXREF104).

Answer (score 2):

Just print it out with NSLog

```
NSLog(@"%@", myObject);
```

It will automatically call the object's `description` method. If this is a class you created, you will want to define that (return an `NSString` with the info).

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289241/how-to-dump-data-stored-in-objective-c-object-nsarray-or-nsdictionary).

Answer (score 1):

The description method of NSObject is similar to inspect

Answer (score 1):

In your NSObject's h file write this :

> - (NSDictionary *)dictionaryRepresentation;

In your NSObject's m file write this :

> - (NSDictionary *)dictionaryRepresentation {
>     unsigned int count = 0;
>     // Get a list of all properties in the class.
>     objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList([self class], &count);
>
>   NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:count];
>
>   for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
>         NSString *key = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:property_getName(properties[i])];
>         NSString *value = [self valueForKey:key];
>
>   ```
>   // Only add to the NSDictionary if it's not nil.
>   if (value)
>       [dictionary setObject:value forKey:key];
>   ```
>
>   }
>
>   free(properties);
>
>   return dictionary; }
> - (NSString *)description {
>     return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self dictionaryRepresentation]]; }