# Is there a var_dump in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

I come from a php background... so I was wondering if there was such a thing as `var_dump` for Xcode, I know about `NSLog` but I want it to act like `var_dump`.

Is there a function for this?

Comment: How about NSLog(@"%@", [myVar description]) ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to dump data stored in objective-c object (NSArray or NSDictionary)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289241/how-to-dump-data-stored-in-objective-c-object-nsarray-or-nsdictionary)

Comment: @BlackRider does that work for arrays?

Comment: Absolutely. It works with arrays and dictionaries. As long as the objects in the array/dictinary return something meaningful in their own `description` method.

Comment: You are looking for introspection or reflection. There are some pretty handy snippets around doing just that even for objects that do not "properly" implement `description`.

Comment: `debugDescription` may provide more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In code:

```
NSLog(@"%@", myVar);
```

which is equivalent to

```
NSLog(@"%@", [myVar description]);
```

Or in the debugger: right click on the variable, and select "Print description".

If you want to inspect objects of your own classes this way, you need to implement the method `-(NSString *)description` for those classes.

Answer (score 9):

In swift you can use dump(var) which uses mirror for introspection and useful for classes.

For example:

```
let pet = Pet(name:"Max", age: 4)
let adam = Person(name:"Adam", age: 30, pet:pet)

print("\(pet)")
print("\(adam)")
print("======")
dump(pet)
dump(adam)
```

The output will be:

```
Pet
Person
======
▿ Pet #0
  - name: "Max"
  - age: 4
▿ Person #0
  - name: "Adam"
  - age: 30
  ▿ pet: Optional(Pet)
    ▿ some: Pet #1
      - name: "Max"
      - age: 4
```

Comment: To use print() or dump() inside a view, you can assign it to a let e.g., `let _ = dump(pet)`.

Answer (score 2):

`NSObject` defines the `description` method, which provides a description of the object. The default implementation just prints the name of the class, but it's commonly overridden by subclasses to provide a more meaningful description of their content.

This is for instance the case of `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`, whose implementation produces a `NSString` representing the objects stored in the  collection.

When you do

```
NSLog(@"%@", anObject);
```

`description` is automatically called on the object to retrieve a textual representation of it.

Also in the debugger you can do

```
po anObject
```

to achieve the same result.

Bottom line, if you need to provide a representation of a custom class you implemented, the way to go is to override `description`.