# How do I display all the information of an object

Tags: ios, nsobject

```
func makeGetRequest(){           
    var url : String = "http://apiairline.sunkhoai.com/api-v2/get-airinfo?ver=2?iata=ALL&direction=ALL"
    var request : NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest ()
    request.URL = NSURL(string: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue(), completionHandler:{ (response:NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        var error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSError?> = nil
        let jsonResult: NSDictionary! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: error) as? NSDictionary

        var _names: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
        if (jsonResult != nil) {
            // Success
            // println(jsonResult)
            let dataArray = jsonResult["airinfo_list"] as NSArray;

            var _names: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
            for item :AnyObject in dataArray{
                let obj = item as NSDictionary
                _names.addObject(item)                                
                self.TableData = _names
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }        
            }

        } else {
            // Failed
            println("Failed")
        }

    })
}
```

how do I display all the information of an object

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
```

how do I display all the information of an object

```
if let airinfo_list = TableData[indexPath.row] as? NSDictionary{
    var ten = airinfo_list.valueForKey("AirNumberEx") as NSString
    cell.textLabel?.text = ten                           
}
return cell
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to show everything in the object, the easiest method is `JSON.stringify(object);`  This will dump everything in the object, you can write it to the console or do an alert, either way that method gives you a string result.

Final Edit:  Disregard my answers.  Your tags have been updated to properly reflect what language you are working in.  Due to similarities, I was giving JS answers when you needed Objective-C.  Properly tagging / explaining your post helps the community know what you want.

Final Final edit:  After looking around on SO, here is probably the answer you need:  [Objective C Introspection/Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299841/objective-c-introspection-reflection)

Comment: Updated answer but I am uncertain what your object name is or where you want it.  I assume it is the obj variable or are you wanting the cell variable?  If so, place the above after your for loop and it will dump the contents of that variable.

Comment: thank you
but I'm still not sure where to put it
help me fix to code

Comment: What is your object?  You have posted 3 functions that all return different things.  I will update the answer with your first function.

Comment: request the post should not have to fix it.

I need to correct in this function
func override tableView (tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier ("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
if let airinfo_list = TableData [indexPath.row] as? NSDictionary {
             var ten = airinfo_list.valueForKey ("AirNumberEx") as NSString
             cell.textLabel? .text = ten
         }
         return cell
     }

Comment: I need the 3rd function

Comment: I have removed my code due to updated tags as explained.

Comment: You might want to look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289241/how-to-dump-data-stored-in-objective-c-object-nsarray-or-nsdictionary or the one I posted above.